# How to Deploy an Amber App on Ubuntu?

Tags: deployment, crystal-lang, amber-framework

Just discovered Amber...looks nice! How can I deploy a sample App on an Ubuntu Server? Should it be done just like Rails, routing the path to `public`? Or some other part of the structure?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amber will serve the static assets for you, just point nginx at port 3000.

This is a good starting point for nginx configuration as a front to Amber running on port 3000:

```
upstream amber {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name _;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://amber;
  }
}
```

Then, start Amber with `AMBER_ENV=production`:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

npm install 
npm run release 
shards build app --production

# if you need it
# export DATABASE_URL="postgres://user:password@hostname:port/database_name"
export AMBER_ENV="production"

exec bin/app
```

This all assumes your amber app is named `app`

Comment: You can use `shards build test --poduction` without running `shards install` before :)

Comment: Yeah that's a good solution. Technically you could also deploy without nginx but that would require running Amber on port 80 or 443 which requires superuser access (usually not recommended) for web apps.

Comment: @NickM Yes, I believe the apache module `proxy` provides essentially the same thing as nginx proxy_pass.